# How to describe angular controller methods in documentation?

Tags: angularjs, documentation, documentation-generation, jsdoc, ngdoc

I can't describe controllers methods. How i can do this?

```
/**
* @ngdoc controller
* @name works.controller:worksCtrl
* @requires $http
* @requires $element
* @function
*
* @description
* Description for works controller. All methods will be writen later
*/
var worksCtrl = function ($http, $element) {

    var ctrl = this;

    //how it do there? this not work
    /** 
        * @name initializeGrid
        * @function
        * @description
        * Description for initializeGrid
    */
    ctrl.initializeGrid = function (a) {
       //...
    }

    ctrl.getTemplate = function (workIndex) {
      //...

    }
    //...
};
```

I am using ngdoc for auto generate documentation. But i can't understand what i do wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
* @ngdoc function
* @name initializeGrid
* @methodOf works.controller:worksCtrl
* @description This method initialize auto grid system for works
* @private
*/

ctrl.initializeGrid = function () {
     ...
}
```

That is what i need.)

Answer (score 4):

I have never used ngdoc but looking to angular code itself, it looks that you need to add a `@ngdoc method` tag to the documentation for internal functions. For example, inside $locationProvider:

```
  /**
   * @ngdoc method
   * @name $locationProvider#hashPrefix
   * @description
   * @param {string=} prefix Prefix for hash part (containing path and search)
   * @returns {*} current value if used as getter or itself (chaining) if used as setter
   */
  this.hashPrefix = function(prefix) {
    if (isDefined(prefix)) {
      hashPrefix = prefix;
      return this;
    } else {
      return hashPrefix;
    }
  };
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not anwer, but this help me to find solution. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I am happy that it helped in an indirect way :)